# Do slaves cost only $90 today?

Tags: slavery

Given how slaves cost tens of thousands of dollars in today's money at the time of the American Civil War, I was surprised to read in a number of places ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_the_21st_century#cite_ref-Economics_and_Slavery2_15-1), [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-slavery-conference-lives/how-much-is-a-life-worth-ask-activists-fighting-slavery-idUSKBN1DG2O4), [CNN](https://thecnnfreedomproject.blogs.cnn.com/2011/03/07/cost-of-slaves-falls-to-historic-low/)) that the average price of a slave today is $90. The ultimate source for these claims appears to be University of Nottingham professor Kevin Bales. In a [paper](https://glc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/events/cbss/Bales.pdf), he asserts that "slaves [are] less expensive today than at any time in the past", based on field observations.

Is this figure accurate? Are there independent sources that back it up?

Comment: You have a book by a university professor, and two reputable news organizations, What would you consider an "independent source" if they are not?

Comment: See also [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2019/feb/25/modern-slavery-trafficking-persons-one-in-200) with a price of $450, [This report by Time](https://time.com/longform/african-slave-trade/) tell of people sold for $200.

Comment: I'd worry of a cherry pick... In what time and place? Surely slave pricing hasn't been relatively constant in the Americas?

Comment: @DJClayworth By "independent" I mean not relying on Bales's figures. Not to say they are untrustworthy, but I'd like to see it backed up by other sources.

Comment: Personally, I struggle to understand why is it so cheap. I tend to think that it's just the same lie repeated many times by the charity-industrial complex to get some emotional empathy and increase donations.

Comment: The wikipedia article touches a few possible reasons - mainly that slaves are not necessarily bought or traded at all. Many get into such a dependency relation through poverty and despair, possibly semi-deliberal. Some even pay someone to be transferred to a first-world country in hope of a better life, but end up in slavery instead. And the usefullness/value for the "owner" may be reduced by slavery being illegal, as it makes it impossible (or at least risky) to use them openly.

Comment: Another possible reason would be if the bulk of todays slavery happens in less developed countries.

Comment: My understanding of this was that direct exchange of cash-for-human was rare, but indentured servitude for an immigration visa was frightengly common, and the cost to the "sponsor" was < $1000 per slave worker. I also understood the money changing hands was rarely buyer-to-seller, but more buyer-to-government for allowing them a permit to bring the slave in.